# Print out lines that begin with two different string outputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to scan an input file and print out parts of lines that begin with a certain string. The text file is 10000+ lines, but I am only concerned with the beginning line, and more specifically the data within that line. For clarification, here are two lines of code which explain what I am trying to say.

```
inst "N69" "IOB",placed BIOB_X11Y0 R8  ,

inst "n0975" "SLICEX",placed CLEXL_X20Y5 SLICE_X32Y5  ,
```

Here is the code that I have gotten to so far:

```
searchfile = open("C:\PATH\TO\FILE.txt","r")
for line in searchfile:
    if "inst " in line: 
        print line
searchfile.close()
```

Now this is great if I am looking for all lines that start with "inst", but I am specifically looking for lines that start with "inst "N"" or "inst "n"". From there, I wanted to extract just the string starting with N  or n.

My idea was to first extract those lines (as shown above) to a new .txt file, then run another script to get only the portions of the lines that have N or n. In the example above, I am only concerned with N69 and n0975. Is there an easier method of doing this?

Comment: Why do you feel you need two scripts, and an intermediate file, for this?  Anything you could possibly do in the second script, you could do in the first script (inside the `if`).

Comment: sorry @jasonharper my python knowledge is a bit rusty and couldn't think of another method. don't get me started on my complete lack of understanding of regular expressions...

Answer (score 1):

With `re.search()` function:

Sample `file.txt` content:

```
inst "N69" "IOB",placed BIOB_X11Y0 R8  ,
some text
inst "n0975" "SLICEX",placed CLEXL_X20Y5 SLICE_X32Y5  ,
text
another text
```

---

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.read().splitlines():
        m = re.search(r'^inst "([Nn][^"]+)"', l)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

The output:

```
N69
n0975
```

Comment: but what about removing the excess data following the n or N values

Comment: when trying to write this to a text file, the data is not listed line by line like in the output of your code. would adding the line `file.write(m.group(1))` do the trick?

Comment: 2.7, but could download the latest version of python 3.XX if necessary

Comment: @nice_remark, yes, upgrade to newer version and share the screenshot with your current output

Comment: the output is similar to what you provided in your original response. but I still cannot figure out how to write the data to a .txt file in that format. I use the sublime text python build system to print the output (which is where i see it output a format similar to your post). when adding `file.write(m.group(1))` to the `if m` statement the output .txt file is one giant line of all the n and N data. for instance the ouput would be N69n0975

Answer (score 1):

Yes with the `re` module.

```
re.finditer(r'^inst\s+\"n(\d+)\"', the_whole_file, re.I)
```

Will return you an iterator of all the matches.
For each match you will need to do `.group(1)` to get those numbers you wanted.

Notice that you don't need to filter the file first using this method. You can do this for the whole file.

The output in your case will be:

```
69
0975
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
with open('nfile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('inst "n') or line.startswith('inst "N'):
            print line.split()[1]
```

For each line in the file `startswith` part checks if the line starts with one of your target patters. If yes, it splits the line using `split` and prints the second component which is the part with `n` or `N`.